# Ĉu oni traduku Esperantlingvajn "-u" verbojn al l'anglalingvaj "Shall" aŭ "Should"?

Tags: translation, verbs

Duolingo tradukas la frazojn

> 1. "Ĉu mi aldonu ajlon aŭ laktukon al la supo?" al "**Should I** add garlic or lettuce to the soup?"
> 2. "Kion ni faru pri tio?" al "What **shall we** do about that?"

Jen miaj demandoj:

1. Ĉu oni povas traduki l'unuan frazon **al "Shall", anstataŭ "Should"**?
2. Ĉu oni povas traduki la duan frazon **al "Should", anstataŭ "Shall"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La angla `shall` estas pli decidema, inklina al ago, ol `should` - kie oni ankaŭ povus nenion fari. La esperanta `-u` tiurilate pli kongruas kun `shall`. Aŭ eĉ `must`, en la unua frazo. Tamen `should` estas pli ĝentila formo, ne tiel postulema por reago, do ambaŭ uzoj taŭgas konsideri.

Comment: Dankegon pro via utila respondo!

Answer (score 2):

PMEG uses the terms *vola modo* and *u-formo* and gives a [definition](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html):

> *U-formo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato ne estas reala, sed dezirata, volata, ordonata aŭ celata. U-formo ne montras la tempon de la ago, sed la ago ordinare troviĝas en la estonteco.*

There are two important observations here:

1. the action is somehow desired or wanted
2. the moment when the wish is expressed the action has not yet happened

My reading of both Esperanto sentences is that I'm making a question about what to do. The first one can be directed to myself (speaking out loud to myself) or to someone else whom I cooking with. In the second sentence I'm part of a group and wondering what course of action we need to take next.

I'm not sufficiently versed in English (not my native language) to say anything definitive, but by quick reading of Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary and its definitions of "[shall](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shall)" and "[should](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/should)", I would say both will do for both sentences.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, and also for that useful link to Oxford's!

Answer (score 1):

La respondo al *Ĉu oni traduku Esperantlingvajn “-u” verbojn al l'anglalingvaj “Shall” aŭ “Should”?* estas *NE* (se vi celas *ĝenerale*). La -u formo havas plurajn signifojn.

Ĉiuokaze via demando rilatas la anglan lingvon pli ol la esperantan. Unue ni vidu kion tiuj konstruoj povus signifi (kur kelkajn ekzemplajn eblojn mi skribas):

```
Ĉu mi aldonu ajlon al la supo?
```

Vi proponas ajlon al manĝanto. Sed, se vi kiel helpanto demandas tion al ĉefkuiristo en la kuirejo, vi tre verŝajne petas permeson tion fari, eĉ ne sugesto tio estus. Vi ricevos respondon kiu rilatas scion, ne volon.

Nun ni ŝangu la pronomon, anstataŭ *mi* ni skribu *vi*:

```
Ĉu vi aldonu ajlon aŭ laktukon al la supo?
```

Tio, dirita de la ĉefkuiristo, estas ĝentila peto tion, fari, tute ne rilatas dubon aŭ volon. Do, alia pronomo ŝanĝas la signifon, kaj do eble ankaŭ la tradukon.

Pri via alia frazo:

```
Kion ni faru pri tio?
```

Tiu estas simpla dubo. Vi konsultas, sed sen propono. En la demando estas eta nuanceto kiu favoras indecon, pli ol endecon. Kunteksto tamen tion plifortigos aŭ preskaŭ nuligos.

Se vi sentas ke *should/shall* esprimas tiujn signifojn, nu, uzu ilin.

Comment: Pardonon, sed mi mem tute scias la signifojn de la frazoj, laŭkuntekste. Do, ne necesis skribi tian longan respondon tute malrilata al mia demando. Mi demandis pri la kialo de traduki tiujn frazojn al "shall/should", ne pri la signifoj de la frazoj!

Comment: Mi bedaŭras pro tio ke vi opinias mian respondon longa kaj nerilatita al la demando. Kiam mi ĝin legis mi pensis ke vi serĉis ian _recepton_ por traduko de tiaj frazoj kaj mi nur volis montri kiel kunteksto povas ŝanĝi iliajn signifojn, kaj do iliajn eblajn tradukojn. Vi konis la kuntekston, sed ni, kiuj volas helpi vin, ne. Espereble la respondo tamen utilos por iu alia.

Comment: Okej, ĉiaokaze dankon pro via provo de helpi min.